# Great Orthogonality Theorem Identity (group theory)

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group of or order n with Γ matrix representations. We define the vector $\psi^{(\Gamma,i,k)}_g=\sqrt{\frac{d_{\Gamma}}{n}}D^{\Gamma}_{ik}(g)$ where $(Γ,i,k)$ is a label, with $i, k ∈
1, . . . , d_Γ$, and where the group element g indexes the components
of $\psi$. The GOT can then be restated as an orthonormality condition on these vectors $\langle \psi^{(\Gamma,i,k)}_g|\psi^{(\Gamma',i',k')}_g\rangle=\delta_{\Gamma,\Gamma'}\delta_{i,i'}\delta_{k,k'}$.
How can we show that $\sum_{Γ}\sum^{d_Γ}_{i,k=1}\psi^{(\Gamma,i,k)}_g\psi^{*(\Gamma,i,k)}_{g'}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{Γ}d_Γ\sum^{d_Γ}_{i,k=1}D^{\Gamma}_{ik}(g)D^{\Gamma*}_{ik}(g')=\delta_{gg'}$